# Hibernate - org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Client is not mapped

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm new to hibernate and I'm trying to solve some problems i cannot understand too well...

For example, I have this query

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Client where clientId = "+clientId+")");
List result = query.list();
```

My Client.hbm.xml is

```
    <class name="it.besmart.models.Client" table="client" catalog="SMARTPARK">
        <id name="idClient" type="int">
            <column name="id_client" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="nomeClient" type="string">
            <column name="nome_client" length="65535" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="numPosti" type="int">
            <column name="num_posti" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="numLuci" type="int">
            <column name="num_luci" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="inizioPosti" type="int">
            <column name="inizio_posti" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="inizioLuci" type="int">
            <column name="inizio_luci" not-null="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The table on the DB is called client and the column is client_id

The mapping in hibernate.cfg.xml is

```
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="parkserver">
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">passwprd</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://192.168.3.67:3306/SMARTPARK</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">parkuser</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="format_sql">true</property>
  <mapping class="it.besmart.models.Client" resource="Client.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping class="it.besmart.models.Illuminazione" resource="Illuminazione.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping class="it.besmart.models.MappaPosti" resource="MappaPosti.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping class="it.besmart.models.Occupazione" resource="Occupazione.hbm.xml"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I'm having no problems in another query in the application, but when i try to executer the SELECT query i got this exception

```
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Client is not mapped [from Client where clientId = 1)]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1836)
    at it.besmart.parkserver.SocketClientHandler.run(SocketClientHandler.java:83)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Client is not mapped
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3678)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3567)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:564)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:262)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:190)
```

I don't know why Client is not mapped, it's correctly in the cfg file...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to add the full name of the class in the query:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from it.besmart.models.Client where clientId = :c");
query.setString("c", clientId)
List result = query.list();
```

I also changed to late binding here which is preferable but has nothing to do with your problem.

As Maurice Perry pointed out in comment below:
- You can also specify the default package in the mapping file: `<hibernate-mapping package="it.besmart.models">`

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem! I was going nuts with the paths and names of entities and cfg...

Comment: You can also specify the default package in the mapping file: <hibernate-mapping package="it.besmart.models">